# Can a single class cause IncompatibleClassChangeError with itself?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Running a java application (that uses spark scala libraries) I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Inconsistent constant pool data in classfile for class org/apache/spark/rpc/RpcEndpoint. Method 'java.lang.String $anonfun$self$1()' at index 49 is CONSTANT_MethodRef and should be CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodRef
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpoint.self(RpcEndpoint.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpoint.self$(RpcEndpoint.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterHeartbeatEndpoint.self(BlockManagerMasterHeartbeatEndpoint.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpoint.stop(RpcEndpoint.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpoint.stop$(RpcEndpoint.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterHeartbeatEndpoint.stop(BlockManagerMasterHeartbeatEndpoint.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterHeartbeatEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(BlockManagerMasterHeartbeatEndpoint.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:103)
    ... 7 more
```

I understood IncompatibleClassChangeError to arise when one class calls another expecting one structure but finds another (e.g. because the library has changed since the client was compiled against it).

However this stacktrace suggests that the error arises from RpcEndpoint calling itself.  How is this possible?  What have I misunderstood?

Further, note that the next class on the stacktrace come from the same jar (spark-core_2.12-3.0.0.jar).

Comment: have you seen the Message "CONSTANT_MethodRef and should be CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodRef"? The message says, that he searched for an implemented method of an Interface but found a normal method. Maybe you forgot a @Override annotation?

Comment: the description here looks relevant, though I haven't found the JDK bug fixed yet... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR-509

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is caused by a combination of

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8147755 (a bug in ASM)

and

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145148 (failing with IncompatibleClassChangeError if ASM not fixed)

showing up because we shaded the spark jar using a version of the shade plugin (2.3) that used the old version of ASM (5.0.2) before it was fixed here

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-228

and then used a version of the JDK that cared about the ASM bug (we used JDK 11.0.6).